# How to count occurences of value inside interval in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

[image: Source and required table]

I have the first table that shows the amount of rain in the city by day. As request, I must display the count of days in which the rain was within an interval, like the second table.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: You could take a look at CASE WHEN & BETWEEN

Comment: what have you tried already? How does your SQL query look like right now? also consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: SUM is your friend

Comment: how to apply SUM at this case ?

Comment: @Hansa, I will try to impove, thank you

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I did it, thank you all !

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT City,
       sum(case when rain = 0               then 1 else 0 end) as '0',
       sum(case when (rain> 0 and rain<= 1) then 1 else 0 end) as ']0-1]',
       sum(case when (rain> 1 and rain<= 2) then 1 else 0 end) as ']1-2]',
       sum(case when (rain> 2)              then 1 else 0 end) as '>2'
FROM MeteoData
group by City;
```